# Opensource v/s custom-developed e-store

Tags: asp.net

I need to develop an *e*-store application in C#.NET. There are number of open-source packages already available, like nopcommerce, dotnetcart and so on. I went through the source code of some  and found them very tedious or to say very deep functional. My requirement is pretty straightforward. Need to have just one level of categorization and a simple and clean front-end. Therefore, i am bit sceptical about using such big solution for a simple e-store.

What do you think ?, should i use the already existing solutions or develop the one accustomed to my requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Ecwid. It very simple, free and easy built shopping cart for any site: http://www.ecwid.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider [Orchard CMS](http://orchardproject.net/) + [e-commerce-module](http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/ByCategory/Modules/Commerce).